# CSS ignore child element but not text

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following HTML

```
<div class='parent'>
  <span>
    <svg /> this is some text 
  </span>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.parent {  
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
svg {
  margin-left: -5px; // <- breaks it
}
```

text-overflow: ellipses; doesn't work here but *does* when I take out the SVG image. Is there a way to add this styling to just the span's text and ignore the svg completely?

example: https://jsfiddle.net/htp7hv0u/1/

Comment: Works for me. At least in Chrome. Maybe you have a competing style? https://jsfiddle.net/htp7hv0u/

Comment: you're right, i didn't give full contect I'll update my post. It's actually because of a negative margin in the svg
https://jsfiddle.net/htp7hv0u/1/

Comment: Are you able to change the markup? If so, I have a solution.

Comment: @TedWhitehead I am to a degree, I'd love to see what you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really weird bug! I was only able to get it to work by changing the markup a little and using flexbox.

```css
.flex {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 80px;
}

.ellip {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Ellipsis Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="flex">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <path d="M30,1h40l29,29v40l-29,29h-40l-29-29v-40z" stroke="#000" fill="none"/> 
      <path d="M31,3h38l28,28v38l-28,28h-38l-28-28v-38z" fill="#a23"/> 
      <text x="50" y="68" font-size="48" fill="#FFF" text-anchor="middle"><![CDATA[410]]></text>
    </svg>

    <p class="ellip">this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text</p>
  </div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Here’s a JSBin demo as well http://jsbin.com/comokuhuwe/edit?html,css,output

Hope that helps!

Comment: I can mark this as the answer as it will solve most peoples issues -- the markup I cannot edit however is the text wrapped in the <p class="ellip"> tag.

Comment: Oh, so there is no way for you to wrap the text in its own element? That might not be possible without JS then. Perhaps this could help https://dollarshaveclub.github.io/shave/